# how to prevent duplicate child record to database for each parent using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am having product variant table in mysql, i want to prevent duplicate child record for each parent product id:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
id | product id | category id | variant_value_id' | title
----------------------------------------------------
1  | 11          | 2          | 7 
2  | 11          | 3          | 7
```

---

this is my mysql table structure. 
i want to have unique variant id for each category id. 
this is my controller

```
foreach($this->input->post('product_variant') as $value){
                        $variant_data = array(
                            'product_id'        => $id,
                            'category_id'       => $this->input->post('product_category'),
                            'variant_group_id'  => $this->Product_model->get_variant_group_by_variant_id($value)[0]->group_id,
                            'variant_value_id'  => $value,
                            'product_variant_title' => $this->input->post('product_name').' '.$this->Product_model->get_variant_group_by_variant_id($value)[0]->value,
                            'mrp_price'         => '',
                            'price'             =>'',
                            'slug'              => url_title($this->input->post('product_name').'-'.$this->Product_model->get_variant_group_by_variant_id($value)[0]->value, 'dash', true),
                            'status'            =>'',
                        );
                        if($this->Product_model->add_product_variant($variant_data)){
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('product_variant_added', 'Product Variant Created Succesfully');
                        }
                    }
```

Please help. if need more info, i will provide

Comment: So you want to prevent duplicate productId?

Comment: yes, but for each category id based. i want variant_value_id field unique for each category id. like if i have mobile, electronic, cloth category. now i color variant in each category but it should not be duplicated in mobile or any other category.

Comment: I've provided a sample. Check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent duplicate productId, then use the following I mean do a check:

```
$q = $this->db->select('ProductName')
     ->from('Table')
     ->where(array('ProductId' => $ProductId, 'variant_value_id' => $variant_value_id))->get(); //Select query to check the productId

    if($q->num_rows() == 0){ //Finally checks if the Id doesn't exist
    //Insert goes here
}
else
{
  //Already exists
}
```

Comment: can you please help with another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676108/how-can-i-create-product-variant-in-codeigniter

Comment: can you please review my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807352/how-to-make-my-codeiginter-password-reset-function-secure