# how can i create product variant in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want to create product variant for any product using codeigniter.
i have product table and product variant table

**product table**

```
------------------------------------------------------
id | category_id | title | price
------------------------------------------------------
1 | 1            | plstic bucket | 200
2 | 2            | Big storage bucket | 500
```

**product variant table**

---

```
variant_id | product_id | title                    | price
------------------------------------------------------
1          | 1          | plstic bucket red small  | 
2          | 1          | plstic bucket red big    | 
3          | 1          | plstic bucket blue small |
4          | 1          | plstic bucket blue big   |
```

and product 
my product variant array:

```
color = red, blue, green;
size = small, medium, large;
capacity = 10ltr, 20lts, 30ltr;
```

i want the save new variants in mysql:

```
red-small-10ltrs; red-medium-20ltrs; red-large-30lts, blue-small-10ltrs
```

and so on.

please suggest me best way or code to do it.
my product controller:

```
foreach($this->input->post('product_variant') as $value){
                    $variant_group_id = $this->Product_model->get_variant_group_by_variant_id($value)[0]->group_id;
                    $variant_data = array(
                        'product_id'        => $id,
                        'category_id'       => $this->input->post('product_category'),
                        'variant_group_id'  => $variant_group_id,
                        'variant_value_id'  => $value,
                        'product_variant_title' => $this->input->post('product_name').' '.$this->Product_model->get_variant_group_by_variant_id($value)[0]->value,
                        'mrp_price'         => '',
                        'price'             =>'',
                        'slug'              => url_title($this->input->post('product_name').'-'.$this->Product_model->get_variant_group_by_variant_id($value)[0]->value, 'dash', true),
                        'status'            =>'',
                    );
                    if($this->Product_model->add_product_variant($id, $variant_group_id, $value, $variant_data)){
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('product_variant_added', 'Product Variant Created Succesfully');
                    }
                }
```

my resulted array is:

```
$first = $this->input->post('product_variant');
Array
(
[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 9
        [2] => 13
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => 12
        [1] => 15
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] => 11
    )

)
```

now what i want to generate combination Like:

```
8,12,7,11
8,15,7,11
9,12,7,11
9,15,7,11
13,12,7,11
13,15,7,11
```

Comment: It's little bit unclear. How you are trying to deal with product_variant?

Comment: Then you have to create another table to keep all the related or relevant info like category, product, product variant etc.

Comment: i have controller to save product varians but it is not saving in right way as i want. added product controller code in question

Comment: Let me make it clear. You want the products selecting product variants with dropdown or vice versa? Is it so?

Comment: yes. like want sort of concatenation between variants values: or any other good way to work with product variants..

Comment: I guess, in the product table, a foreign key exists for product variant. Just do a inner join and concatenate the rows. You can do concatenation in MYSQL. Finally you will have it in the drop down.

Comment: so any suggestion?

Comment: product variant is a different table and I guess, you have a value of the table in the product table too. Just join the tables to get the variants in the drop down using concatenation. Is it clear now? By the way, do you have any columns of the product variant table in the product table?

Comment: i have separate table for products and product variants. in product variant table product id is key from product table.

Comment: Then ok. Do a INNER JOIN and concatenate with MySQL.

Comment: Did it work? Let me know. Use GROUP_CONCAT() for MySQL to concatenate.

Comment: hi added array to generate combination to understand the requirement. please see and reply.