# How to make my codeiginter password reset function secure?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have written a user password and emailing code in codeignter.

I have created controller for recovering password. My code send temporary password on email with get URL and I validate that URL and store new password to database.

Now how I can I make this code more secure and reliable.

my controller:

```
public function recover(){
    $data['main_content'] = 'auth/recover';
    $this->load->view('public/layouts/home_main', $data);
}
public function recover_account(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|xss_clean|required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            //Show View
            $data = array(
                'errors' => validation_errors()
            );
            $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
            $data['main_content'] = 'auth/recover';
            $this->load->view('public/layouts/home_main', $data);
        }
        else{
            $account = $this->input->post('username');
            if($this->User_model->user_exist($account)){
                $options = [
                    'cost' => 8,
                    'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
                ];
                $temp_pass = password_hash(rand(23456,975655), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
                $reset_code = rand(23456,975655);
                $data = array(
                    'reset_link_code' => $reset_code
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);

                $this->email->from('info@netbeam.in', 'Your Name');
                $this->email->to('vikas@onusworld.com');
                $this->email->subject($reset_code);
                $this->email->message(
                    'Testing the email class.'.' pass: <a href="'.base_url().'auth/reset_password?user='.urlencode($account).'&code='.urlencode($temp_pass).'&rstc='.urlencode($reset_code).'">Click Here</a>'
                );
                $db_pass = array(
                    'password' => $temp_pass
                );
                $this->db->where('email', $account);
                $this->db->or_where('username', $account);
                $this->db->update('users', $db_pass);

                if($this->email->send()){
                    echo 'Passowrd resend link sent to email';
                }else{
                    echo 'email count not check, pls talk to support';
                }
            }else{
                echo "User not Fount";
            }
        }
    }
    function reset_password(){
        $email = urldecode($this->input->get('user', true));
        $temp_pass = urldecode($this->input->get('code', true));
        $reset_code = urldecode($this->input->get('rstc', true));
        if($email && $temp_pass && $reset_code){

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('user','Username','trim|xss_clean|min_length[4]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpass','Password','trim|xss_clean|required|min_length[4]|max_length[50]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpass2','Confirm Password','trim|xss_clean|required|matches[newpass]');

            if($reset_code == $this->session->userdata('reset_link_code')){
                $db_pass = $this->User_model->get_heshed_password($email);
                if($temp_pass == $db_pass){
                    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                        //Show View
                        $data = array(
                            'errors' => validation_errors()
                        );
                        $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
                        $data['main_content'] = 'auth/reset_password';
                        $this->load->view('public/layouts/home_main', $data);
                    }
                    else{
                        $options = [
                            'cost' => 8,
                            'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
                        ];
                        $password = $this->input->post('newpass');
                        $passtodb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
                        $data = array(
                            'password' => $passtodb
                        );
                        $this->db->where('email', $email);
                        $this->db->or_where('username', $email);
                        $this->db->update('users', $data);
                        redirect('account');
                    }

                }   
            }else{
                echo 'invalid reset code';
            }

        }else{
            redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

my view files:

```
    <?php if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) : ?>
    <section style="background:#ccc;padding-top:20px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="coupon-area">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1 ac-form-login">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Recover Password</h4>
                            <hr class="separator">
                            <br>
                            <?php if($this->session->flashdata('errors')) : ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('errors'); ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <div>
                                <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>auth/recover_account" method="post">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-input-modal" placeholder="Enter your registered email" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class=" col-sm-6">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Recover Password</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <br>

                            <hr class="separator">
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php redirect('account'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

my password reset form:

```
    <?php if(!$this->session->userdata('loged_i')):?>
    <section style="background:#ccc;padding-top:20px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="coupon-area">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1 ac-form-login">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Recover Password</h4>
                            <hr class="separator">
                            <br>
                            <?php if($this->session->flashdata('errors')) : ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('errors'); ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <div>
                                <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>auth/reset_password?user=<?php echo urlencode($this->input->get('user', true)).'&code='.urlencode($this->input->get('code', true)).'&rstc='.urlencode($this->input->get('rstc', true));?>" method="post">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <input type="text" name="user" class="form-input-modal form-control" value="<?php echo urldecode($this->input->get('user', true));?>" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <input type="password" name="newpass" class="form-input-modal" placeholder="Set Password" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                                            <input type="password" name="newpass2" class="form-input-modal" placeholder="Confirm Set Password" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class=" col-sm-6">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Reset Password</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <br>

                            <hr class="separator">
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </section>
   <?php else: ?>
   <?php redirect('account'); ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

My problem is I want to make this code more user friendly and secure, so that I can prevent SQL injection and other issue.

Comment: I hope, you have done encryption and decryption to make the passwords secure.

Comment: yes. this is right.

Comment: I would also add a time limit for using password reset.

Comment: @cssBlaster21895 thank you for comment. can you make changes into code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read your code and I think even if I add time limit for using new token it is still not secure. According to [owasp cheatsheat on password recovery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Forgot_Password_Cheat_Sheet), you can do better than that. I shorten it a little for you. They name five points.

1. Use some data that you collected in user registration process - it can be birthday, mobile phone number, surname etc.
2. Use security questions, and put the answer inputs as pure text, don't do dropdown or anything like that. Limit here the number of guesses. Be non trivial and inventive in constructing those questions.
3. After step two, it is recommended to lock user account imidiatelly. Generate time limited password token and send it(at least try to) through different communication channel, maybe with sms, or to secondary email.
4. Keep an eye on session, and allow to reset password only during current session. Enforce password complexicity in this step, (you can use some jquery plugin for that).
5. Try to log user actions, ip address, browser data. Focus on failed attempts or using expired tokens. This way you can monitor malicious behaviours and draw some conclusions.

And here's my little upgrade. I use updated_at column, which can be useful in many other situations or you may specify your own column only for limiting resetting password time.

```
<?php

public function recover(){
    $data['main_content'] = 'auth/recover';
    $this->load->view('public/layouts/home_main', $data);
}

public function recover_account(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|xss_clean|required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        //Show View
        $data = array(
            'errors' => validation_errors()
        );
        $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
        $data['main_content'] = 'auth/recover';
        $this->load->view('public/layouts/home_main', $data);
    }
    else{
        $account = $this->input->post('username');
        if($this->User_model->user_exist($account)){
            $options = [
                'cost' => 8,
                'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
            ];
            $temp_pass = password_hash(rand(23456,975655), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
            $reset_code = rand(23456,975655);
            $data = array(
                'reset_link_code' => $reset_code
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);

            $this->email->from('info@netbeam.in', 'Your Name');
            $this->email->to('vikas@onusworld.com');
            $this->email->subject($reset_code);
            $this->email->message(
                'Testing the email class.'.' pass: <a href="'.base_url().'auth/reset_password?user='.urlencode($account).'&code='.urlencode($temp_pass).'&rstc='.urlencode($reset_code).'">Click Here</a>'
            );
            $db_pass = array(
                'password' => $temp_pass,
                'updated_at' => time() //or even date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
            );
            $this->db->where('email', $account);
            $this->db->or_where('username', $account);
            $this->db->update('users', $db_pass);

            if($this->email->send()){
                echo 'Passowrd resend link sent to email';
            }else{
                echo 'email count not check, pls talk to support';
            }
        }else{
            echo "User not Fount";
        }
    }
}
function reset_password(){
    $email = urldecode($this->input->get('user', true));
    $temp_pass = urldecode($this->input->get('code', true));
    $reset_code = urldecode($this->input->get('rstc', true));

    if($email && $temp_pass && $reset_code){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user','Username','trim|xss_clean|min_length[4]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpass','Password','trim|xss_clean|required|min_length[4]|max_length[50]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpass2','Confirm Password','trim|xss_clean|required|matches[newpass]');

        if($reset_code == $this->session->userdata('reset_link_code')){
            //get user data by email
            //$user = $this->User_model->get_heshed_password($email);
            $user = $this->User_model->get_heshed_password_and_updated_value($email);

            //calculate time difference
            $dbdate = strtotime($user->updated_at);
            if (time() - $dbdate > 15 * 60) {
                // 15 mins has passed
                $time_allowed = false;
            } else {
                $time_allowed = true;
            }

            if($temp_pass == $user->password && $time_allowed){
                if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                    //Show View
                    $data = array(
                        'errors' => validation_errors()
                    );
                    $this->session->set_flashdata($data);
                    $data['main_content'] = 'auth/reset_password';
                    $this->load->view('public/layouts/home_main', $data);
                }
                else{
                    $options = [
                        'cost' => 8,
                        'salt' => mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM),
                    ];
                    $password = $this->input->post('newpass');
                    $passtodb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
                    $data = array(
                        'password' => $passtodb
                    );
                    $this->db->where('email', $email);
                    $this->db->or_where('username', $email);
                    $this->db->update('users', $data);
                    redirect('account');
                }

            }
        }else{
            echo 'invalid reset code';
        }

    }else{
        redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheer up, most popular auth library for ci isn't also that strict. I can write this piece of code, but later :) For now you can take a peek https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/2/libraries/Ion_auth.php#L274  , you can do something similar.